# How to look up the size of free elements in the mempool of open-vswitch with command or debug file?

Tags: c, openvswitch, memory-pool

I am debuging the open-vswitch and want to find the size of free elements in one mempool. I use the command:

```
ovs-appctl netdev-dpdk/get-mempool-info dpdkr0 | grep -v "cache_count\["
```

And I get the output:

```
mempool <ovs_mp_9198_0_65536>@0x7fff8861bb00
flags=10
pool=0x7fff878ffd80
iova=0x42761bb00
nb_mem_chunks=1
size=65536
populated_size=65536
header_size=64
elt_size=10112
trailer_size=0
total_obj_size=10176
private_data_size=64
avg bytes/object=10176.000000
internal cache infos:
cache_size=512
total_cache_count=513
common_pool_count=64767
no statistics available
```

But I do not know which line is my aim? If there is no aim in the output, how can I find it?

Comment: I was told that the common_pool_count was the correct result.

Comment: OK, the problem was solved. In fact, I first found the link 'https://www.mankier.com/8/ovs-vswitchd#Runtime_Management_Commands-Netdev-Dpdk_Commands' about the command introduction and then got the function called --'rte_mempool_dump'. Looking into the function and found the common_pool_count is the aim. Reading the codes is always the best way and why the team of DPDK call it 'common_pool_count'...